# How to get GDC info into Log4JXMLEvent

Tags: nlog

I see here how to get MDC and MDLC, but no GDC. Is this by design?

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Log4JXMLEvent-Layout-Renderer

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own custom Log4JXML-parameters, as you can see on the wiki-page:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/NLogViewer-target

There you can specify individual GDC-parameters using the GDC-layout-renderer:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-layout-renderer

Strange enough then it is not possible to specify parameters using the Log4JXmlEventLayout, but one have to use the NLogViewer-target.